# Resource "kubernetes_annotations" not being created for Service Account

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform, amazon-eks, terragrunt

I got the  issue upon upgrade our EKS cluster from 1.22 to 1.23 using Terraform v1.3.6, we encountered an error stating no matches for kind "ServiceAccount" in version "v1".

This error arises when trying to re-apply a ServiceAccount annotation resource using the kubernetes_annotations resource. The same Terraform configuration works fine on EKS 1.22 but throws the aforementioned error on EKS 1.23.

```
resource "kubernetes_annotations" "ebs-csi-sa" {
  api_version = "v1"
  kind        = "ServiceAccount"

  metadata {
    name      = "ebs-csi-controller-sa"
    namespace = "kube-system"
  }

  annotations = {
    "eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn" = module.ebs-csi-irsa[0].iam_role_arn
  }
}
```

│

```
Error: no matches for kind "ServiceAccount" in version "v1"
│   with kubernetes_annotations.ebs-csi-sa[0],
│   on main.tf line 192, in resource "kubernetes_annotations" "ebs-csi-sa":
│  192: resource "kubernetes_annotations" "ebs-csi-sa" {
```

Can you please help us understand what's causing this and suggest possible solutions?

Environment:

Terraform Version: v1.3.6
kubectl 1.23.17
EKS Version: v1.23 (issue), v1.22 (works fine)
terraform providers:

gavinbunney/kubectl v1.14.0...
hashicorp/kubernetes v2.21.1
hashicorp/aws v5.1.0...

Comment: That error message does not seem to match the config code snippet.

Comment: why ? @MattSchuchard